# GTKMM: Take a screen shot of an DrawingArea?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I Have a Drawing Area that I draw some figures or images inside, so I have this callback to take screenshots:

```
void CanvasToolBox::actionCanvasCamera()
{
    auto root = Gdk::Window::get_default_root_window();
    int height = root->get_height();
    int width = root->get_width();
    auto pixels = Gdk::Pixbuf::create(root, 0, 0, width, height);
    pixels->save("s.png", "png");
}
```

That code takes a screenshot of the whole screen..
But I need to take the screenshot of a especific window a Gtk::DrawingArea in my case.. so the function `create` needs a Gdk::Window as a parameter.
Is there any way to take a screenshot of a Gtk especific window?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to GTKmm (I use C and Python APIs instead), but with your example, that looks pretty straightforward. You just want to use your `Gtk::DrawingArea` instead of the root window. So you search in the documentation of [`Gdk::Window::get_default_root_window`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Window.html#a67dd93686b7a8542e9eb4f464a3f4265) and find that it returns a `Gdk::Window`.

Now you have to find how to get a `Gdk::Window` out of a `Gtk::DrawingArea`. So you go to the documentation of [`Gtk::DrawingArea`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html) and search for a function that returns a `Gdk::Window`, and then find this is [`Gtk::Widget::get_window`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a403777253417c5c7653aac9e932de76b), which is inherited from `Gtk::Widget`. BTW, you may prefer the const version, as you don't modify the window, just read it.

You can then replace code that gets the root windows with a call to get the `Gdk::Window` of the widget you care about, and you're done. If you want to go further, instead of using `Gdk::Pixbuf`, there may be a way to use a cairo context.